# Migration to Azure Resource Manager

Tags: azure, vmware, azure-virtual-machine

I'm doing some research to migrate virtual machines(vmware) to the new Azure Resource Manager portal.

I already succeeded doing this with powershell. But I was wondering if there where other methods to do this faster and more efficient with less downtime?

Answer (score 0):

There is the Azure Site Recovery:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-site-recovery-ga-move-vmware-aws-hyper-v-and-physical-servers-to-azure/

"Customers can replicate on-premises workloads to Azure with Azure Site Recovery for 31 days at no charge, effectively making migration to Azure free."

Comment: As far as my research goes from Azure Site recovery it only works with the Azure classic portal in the past. Now i see that it also works with Azure Resource Manager but only with Hyper-V and not with VMWare.

Also this stores the virtual machines in a safe rather than directly underneath Azure itself so it will cost more after the 31 days.

Answer (score 0):

I do enjoy the cunning of @alexandr's solution! However the official solution from Microsoft is that they are currently building the tools to automate this for you.

from the [Transitioning to the Resource Manager model](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/transitioning-to-the-resource-manager-model/) blog. There are a basic set of [scripts](https://github.com/fullscale180/asm2arm) and a timeline for the more complex migrations (no VNet etc)

To directly answer your question, it seems like Powershell is the tool of choice for managing the migration. (I imagine if you leave it for long enough there will be a 'migrate' button in the portal, as they seem very eager to move everyone away from ASM)